# Polynomial inequality $n^2\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^3$

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n\ge 3$ be an integer. I would like to know if the following property $(P_n)$ holds: for all real numbers $a_i$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\geq0 $ and  $\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}a_ia_ja_k\geq0$, we have
$$n^2\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^3.$$
I have a proof that $(P_n)$ holds for $3\leq n\leq8$, but for $n\geq9$ my method does not work and I did not see any counterexample for $n\ge 9$.

Is the inequality $(P_n)$ true for all $n$? Or otherwise, what is the largest value of $n$ for which it holds?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more precise on "it seems that it's wrong for a big value of $n$"? you have an explicit counterexample? for some explicit $n$?

Comment: @YCor I have no a counterexample. See please better my post.

Comment: But in your post you say "it seems that it's wrong for a big value of $n$". What makes you believe that it's wrong for some large $n$? you wrote you have no counterexample for $n=9$.

Comment: @YCor  I just think so because I solved during my live one problem or maybe two. Can I think so?  You do not allow me? :)

Comment: Well, it's confusing, as it conveys some wrong information. I edited your post; of course you can write that your guess is that it fails for large $n$, but "it seems" suggested that you have a serious reason to believe so.

Comment: Note that if you decrease all exponents by 1 (replace 3 by 2 and 2 by 1), it becomes a corollary of Cauchy-Schwartz without any restriction on $a_i$.

Comment: Than you,  Mark! It's OK. For me more interesting, how we can approach to  this task. For exponent $2$ it's obvious, of course.

Comment: The inequality is always true if all summands are equal (it becomes an equality). Did you try to take derivatives with respect to $a_i$ to show that the inequality becomes strict for different summands? (For some reason I think that the inequality is true for every $n$.)

Comment: I checked  that for $n=9$ and $a_2=...=a_9$ it's true.

Comment: Now you can try taking derivative with repspect to $a_2$. When I was in high school, I was taught to prove inequalities that way.

Comment: @Mark Sapir When I was in high school, I was taught that nothing does not help, when we need to prove inequalities.

Comment: Did you try $pqr$-method? (I mean, fix all variables except $a_1,a_2,a_3$, also fix $\sum a_i$ and $\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}a_ia_ja_k$.)

Comment: @Fedor Petrov I proved it for $3\leq n\leq 8$ by using of the $uvw$'s method and Rolle For $n\geq9$ it does not work, I think. Maybe I don't see something.

Comment: With Rolle (applied $n-3$ times to $\prod (x-a_i)$) it gives something which is wrong for large $n$. But I think Rolle does not reduce an inequality to the equivalent one: the antiderivative of a polynomial with real roots only may fail to have real roots only. I suggested something less elegant and straightforward: is three variables are mutually distinct, we may vary them so that the difference LHS-RHS increases. It reduces the problem to the situation when $a_i$'s take only two different values.

Comment: [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFjjsOgzAQRHufYkpsGYlPlSicJErhECNZineRWSSOH0w-0GXK3Zk3MySOCOKTMD8nhDhyEoyJH3MvFj3HeyAngWlSitDhpAZOcG710tdXXMvGlrWtbG2bm0Xyo3fSkT4rrAoDpjkWa0bjgup9zOqZJNDsj66MLBaN3LLkjuOEzLBo9R8OGdPAbLjFmHZnfSb81hiDdseMKZBsjxfPYVEx&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (actually just Python) gives $(-2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ as a counterexample for $n=9$. Can you check?

Comment: It could be much more harder than olympiad problem if it were true.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: This contradicts a comment from the OP, but it is true.

Comment: Thank you very much, Darij !!!

Comment: For  nonnegative arguments, the inequality in question follows from the power mean inequality.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev Or Holder, or Jensen, or the Vasc's EV, or more and more...

Comment: Is it obvioussly  true if we take $a_0+a_1....+a_n=0$?

Comment: $111$ taken $9$ times and $-199$ gives a counterexample for $n=10$ with a positive sum of cubes (more generally $a+\frac{1}{10}$ taken $9$ times and $-9a+\frac{1}{10}$ for $a > \frac{3}{80}$ and close to it - $a=\frac{3}{80}+\frac{1}{800}$ and normalizing to integers gives the above

Comment: @jcdornano yes: $6\sum a_i^3=(\sum a_i)^3-3(\sum a_i)(\sum a_i a_j)+3\sum a_i a_j a_k$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: True. I have removed my suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

Take $n=3k$, $2k$ variables equal to $3$ and $k$ variables equal to $-5$ for large $k$. Then $\sum a_i=k>0$, and $\sum_{i<j<k} a_ia_ja_k=\frac16 (\sum a_i)^3+O(k^2)=\frac{k^3}6+O(k^2)>0$ for large $k$. But $\sum a_i^3<0$.

Comment: Thank you, Fedor!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a long comment, but translating to the notation of symmetric functions, you ask if
whenever $e_{111}(x) \geq 0$ and $e_3(x) \geq 0$, we have
$$
n^2 p_{(3)}(x) \geq p_{111}(x).
$$
This latter is equivalent with
$$
n^2 \left( 
3e_3-3e_{21}+e_{111}
\right) \geq e_{111}.
$$
Perhaps one can try different bases and see if something nice pops out...

Answer (score 0):

A sort of (partial) explanation for what happens:

Let $N \ge 3$ the degree and let $A=\sum{a_k}, B=\sum_{j<k}a_ja_k, C=\sum_{j\ne k\ne m \ne j}a_ja_ka_m $. We are given that $A \ge 0, C \ge 0$ and we need to prove that $N^2(A^3-3AB+3C) \ge A^3$. Now we can assume wlog $A =1$ since if $A=0$ the inequality is obvious and otherwise we can divide by $A>0$ and consider $c_j=\frac{a_j}{A}$ and prove the inequality for them etc

So we need to prove $1-3B+3C \ge \frac{1}{N^2}$ under the hypothesis as above (the polynomial $X^N-X^{N-1}+BX^{N-2}-CX^{N-3}+...$ has real roots and $C \ge 0$

Then if we let $b_j=a_j-\frac{1}{N}, A_1,B_1,C_1$ the corresponding symmetric polynomials in $b_j$ we have $A_1=0, B_1=B-\frac{N-1}{2N}=B-\frac {1}{2}+\frac{1}{2N}, C_1=C-B+\frac{2B}{N}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{3N^2}$ so the inequality becomes ($C-B=C_1+...$ from the last equality)

$1+3C_1-\frac{6B}{N}-1+\frac{3}{N}-\frac{2}{N^2}\ge \frac{1}{N^2}$ and since

$\frac{6B}{N}=\frac{6B_1}{N}+\frac{3}{N}-\frac{3}{N^2}$ all reduces to

$3C_1-\frac{6B_1}{N} \ge 0$

But now the polynomial $X^N+B_1X^{N-2}-C_1X^{N-3}+...$ has real roots too as they are just $b_k$ and hence $B_1 \le 0, B_1=-B_2, B_2 \ge 0$ so the inequality reduces to $2B_2+NC_1 \ge 0$ and we know that $C_1=C+\frac{N-2}{N}B_2-\frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{6N^2}$

So we need $C_1$ negative but $C \ge 0$

By differentiating $N-3$ times and using Gauss Lucas/Rolle (so the cubic that results which is in standard form) has real roots so $4(-p)^3 \ge 27q^2$, we get some constraints on $B_2, -C_1$ which are enough to give the result for $N \le 6$ with some crude approximations

Then if we try easy counterexamples for the $b_k$ of the type $N-1$ $a$ and one $-(N-1)a$ we can solve at $N=10$, $a > \frac{3}{80}$ close enough to it to satisfy the inequality $C>0$ (which is satisifed at $a=\frac{3}{80}$ that one giving equality in the OP inequality as normalizing to integers we get $11$ taken $9$ times, $-19$ taken once and it is easy to see that the constraints are good and $S_1=80, S_3=5120$ and obviously $100\cdot 5120=80^3$

So as noted in the comments taking $9$ of $111$ and one of $-199$ gets a counterexample with a positive sum of cubes (corresponding to $a=\frac{3}{80}+\frac{1}{800}$ normalized to integers)